# Pass List to method without modifying original list

Tags: c#, list, pass-by-reference

Is this the only way of passing a List to a method and editing that List, without modifying the original List?

```
class CopyTest1
{
    List<int> _myList = new List<int>();
    public CopyTest1(List<int> l)
    {
        foreach (int num in l)
        {
            _myList.Add(num);
        }
        _myList.RemoveAt(0); // no effect on original List
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this `a` way of passing a List to a method and editing that List, without modifying the original List?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

duplicate the list:

```
_myLocalList = new List<int>(_myList);
```

and perform the operations on the local list.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`AsReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx) for this:

```
class CopyTest1
{
    List<int> _myList = new List<int>();
    public CopyTest1(IList<int> l)
    {
        foreach (int num in l)
        {
            _myList.Add(num);
        }
        _myList.RemoveAt(0); // no effect on original List
    }
}
```

And call it via `CopyTest1(yourList.AsReadOnly())` .

Answer (score 3):

There is another way. You can use the copy constructor of `List<T>`:

```
List<int> _myList;
public CopyTest1(List<int> l)
{
    _myList = new List<int>(l);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Clone objects in the list to other list and work on this copy

```
static class Extensions
{
        public static IList<T> Clone<T>(this IList<T> listToClone) where T: ICloneable
        {
                return listToClone.Select(item => (T)item.Clone()).ToList();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a list to a method you pass a pointer to said list, that's why your changing the 'original' list when you modify it inside your method. If you instead want to modify a copy of the list you just need to make one. In the code that calls CopyTest1 you can create a new list based on your original list:

```
public void CallsCopyTest1()
{
    var originalList = new List<int>();
    var newList = new List<int>(originalList);
    var copyTest = new CopyTest1(newList); //Modifies newList not originalList
}
class CopyTest1
{
    List<int> _myList = new List<int>();
    public CopyTest1(List<int> l)
    {
        foreach (int num in l)
        {
            _myList.Add(num);
        }
        _myList.RemoveAt(0); // no effect on original List
    }
}
```

Comment: If the callers forgets to create a copy then they will get unexpected behaviour - I would prefer for the class\method to handle it

Comment: That depends what the purpose of the class is, is it do modify a collection or to create a copy of a collection and modify it? The example is a bit contrived and I don't think it's obvious exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass an object by reference doing the following:

```
public static void ReferenceMethod(ref List<T> myParam) {
    ...
}
```

EDIT: The question has now been clarified, the OP was after a way not to alter the original list.

Comment: and in any case it is not necessary to pass it as `ref` to alter the original list -- `ref` allows you to change the reference in the caller's scope to point to another object, something that is highly unlikely to be useful